# 7.0.1 and Photoshop openGL requirements

Tags: vmware-workstation, opengl

I'm running Workstation 7.0.1 on a 64-bit Linux host, with a Vista guest, and the Aero theme works a treat - full marks for getting that working!

However, when running Photoshop there are some operations (like interactive image rotation) that seem to require graphics support that VMWare doesn't have - attempting to do these operations returns an error that the functionality "only works with OpenGL enabled windows".

It seems that it needs OpenGL 2.0 and Shader Model 3.0 which I gather are supported under Workstation 7 - do I need to put in additional settings of some kind? I've updated to the right version of VMWare Tools, and the video driver is listed as "VMWare SVGA 3D (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM)". I see that in 6.5 there was an option to switch between the beta WDDM driver and the SVGAII driver, but I assume the features of both of these would have been merged into the standard driver in 7.0?

Thanks

-Matthew

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](http://pubs.vmware.com/ws7_ace26/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws_user&file=intro_sysreqs_ws.html)'s a link to a good 'how to do hardware DX/OpenGL with WS' document - there's loads of checks for you to be sure you're setup right.

Also what virtual machine model version is the VM? it needs to be the latest to support the beta WDDM vmtools driver.

Answer (score 1):

A Microsoft-provided WDDM video driver won't support OpenGL beyond 1.1 (and it won't even be hardware accelerated) - if at all.  VMWare Player 3.0 seems to come with an appropriate driver, but I can't vouch for it.  [Clicky](http://www.vmware.com/support/player30/doc/releasenotes_player3.html).